# Vanishing partition function

Tags: quantum-mechanics, supersymmetry, path-integral, partition-function, grassmann-numbers

I am currently stuck with the following partition function

Let the action be $$S(X, \psi^1, \psi^2) = \frac{1}{2} (\partial h)^2 - \partial^2h\psi^1 \psi^2 ,\tag{9.29}$$
where $h$ is a real function of the bosonic variable $X$, $\partial h = h'$ and $ \psi^i$ are Grassmann odd variables.
The action is invariant under
$$ \delta X = \epsilon^1 \psi_1 + \epsilon^2 \psi_2$$
$$ \delta \psi_1 = \epsilon^2 \partial h,\tag{9.30}$$
$$ \delta \psi_2 = -\epsilon^1 \partial h,$$
with $\epsilon^i$ Grassmann odd variables.

Now Suppose $\partial h$ is nowhere $0$, i have to show that the corresponding partition function
$$ Z = \int dX d\psi^1 d\psi^2 e^{-S}= 0.\tag{9.31}$$

After a change of variables
$$ \hat{X} = X - \frac{\psi^1 \psi^2}{\partial h}$$
$$ \hat{\psi}^1= \alpha(X) \psi^1\tag{9.32}$$
$$ \hat{\psi}^2= \psi^1 + \psi^2,$$
such that $$S(X,\psi^1,\psi^2) = S(\hat{X}, 0,\hat{\psi}^2),\tag{9.33}$$
with $\alpha$ an arbitrary function of $X$, and some Grassmann integration, i get that

$$Z = -\int e^{-S(\hat{X}, 0, \hat{\psi}^2) } \frac{\partial^2h}{(\partial h)^2} \hat{\psi}^1 \hat{\psi}^2 d \hat{X} d \hat{\psi}^1 d \hat{\psi}^2\tag{9.35}$$

which should be zero. But i can not see why? I got the hint that the integrand is a total derivative in $ \hat{X}$ but that didn't help me.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by $\partial^2{h}{(\partial h)^2}$, this should be zero.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/376564/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/324024/2451

Comment: It is not quite a duplicate since i can not see why this last integral is a total derivative.

Comment: Can we reopen this question please? I was just about to ask this question myself and I don't think the linked "answer" actually answers it.

Comment: Is there something in particular that needs to be clarified?